# How to add a window icon in Bevy?

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm making a game in rust and I want it to be legit. Bevy ECS is great. I have been following tutorials and reading documentation, but there is this one thing I want to know. Can I change the window icon? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to do. You may see discussion of the problem [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/1031), and pr [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/5488) and [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/2268). I am sure it will be solved in a nice standard way soon, meanwhile there is hacky way to do it described [here](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/window/icon.html)

```
use bevy::window::WindowId;
use bevy::winit::WinitWindows;
use winit::window::Icon;

fn set_window_icon(
    // we have to use `NonSend` here
    windows: NonSend<WinitWindows>,
) {
    let primary = windows.get_window(WindowId::primary()).unwrap();

    // here we use the `image` crate to load our icon data from a png file
    // this is not a very bevy-native solution, but it will do
    let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {
        let image = image::open("my_icon.png")
            .expect("Failed to open icon path")
            .into_rgba8();
        let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
        let rgba = image.into_raw();
        (rgba, width, height)
    };

    let icon = Icon::from_rgba(icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height).unwrap();

    primary.set_window_icon(Some(icon));
}

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(set_window_icon)
        .run();
}
```

Comment: I put that code in and it keeps saying that "image is unknown" on line 14

Comment: I found the problem. You need to also import the image library.

Comment: `cargo add image` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

### bevy 0.10 ~ 0.11

##### Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
bevy = "0.11.0"
image = "*"
winit = "0.28.6"
```

##### systems.rs

```rust
use bevy::winit::WinitWindows;
use bevy::{prelude::*, window::PrimaryWindow};
use winit::window::Icon;

pub fn set_window_icon(
    main_window: Query<Entity, With<PrimaryWindow>>,
    windows: NonSend<WinitWindows>,
) {
    let Some(primary) = windows.get_window(main_window.single()) else {return};

    let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {
        let image = image::open("icon.ico")
            .expect("Failed to open icon path")
            .into_rgba8();
        let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
        let rgba = image.into_raw();
        (rgba, width, height)
    };

    let icon = Icon::from_rgba(icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height).unwrap();
    primary.set_window_icon(Some(icon));
}
```